# Pandas - check if values in column match one of two formats

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

In my dataframe, I have a column that will contain a date. It should only be accepted if the format is 'YYYYMMDD' or 'MMDD'. In addition, if the format is 'MMDD',  the year should be taken from another column and appended into the MMDD date like so;

```
  df['YYYYMMDD'] = df['YYYY'].astype(str) + df['Date'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.zfill(4))
```

After the append, the old column is deleted and the new column renamed to the desired output.

For the match, I've tried regex (`df_ori['Date'].str.matches(r'^\d{8}$')`) but I get the error;

`AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`.

I try `df_ori['Date'].astype(str).str.matches(r'^\d{8}$')` and it gives the error;

`'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'matches'`

I think I'm just going about this the wrong way really. Any help is appreciated.

df.head() as requested:

```
   YYYY  MMDD
0  2016   525
1  2016   728
2  2014   821
3  2016   311
4  2016   422
```

Comment: Are the column values strings or datetime objects?  Please post `df.head()` or a minimal example. -- [mcve]

Comment: The column values are integers. I'll add the df.head() to the main post.

Answer (score 1):

You need [`str.match`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.match.html) and [`str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
df['YYYYMMDD'] = df['YYYY'].astype(str) + df['Date'].astype(str).str.zfill(4)

print (df_ori['YYYYMMDD'].astype(str).str.match(r'^\d{8}$'))
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
Name: YYYYMMDD, dtype: bool
```

If want `4` or `8` match:

```
print (df_ori['YYYYMMDD'].astype(str).str.match(r'^\d{8}$|^\d{4}$'))
```

If want from 4 to 8 match:

```
print (df_ori['YYYYMMDD'].astype(str).str.match(r'^\d{4,8}$'))
```

EDIT:

If need append only if len is `4`:

```
print (df_ori)
   YYYY  MMDD  YYYYMMDD
0  2016   525  20160525
1  2016   728  20160728
2  2014  1121      1121
3  2016  1211      2211
4  2016   422  20160422

a = df_ori['YYYY'].astype(str) + df_ori['YYYYMMDD'].astype(str)
m = df_ori['YYYYMMDD'].astype(str).str.len() == 4
df_ori['YYYYMMDD'] = df_ori['YYYYMMDD'].mask(m, a)
print (df_ori)
   YYYY  MMDD  YYYYMMDD
0  2016   525  20160525
1  2016   728  20160728
2  2014  1121  20141121
3  2016  1211  20162211
4  2016   422  20160422
```

Comment: That matches for the YYYYMMDD format, but it can also be MMDD and if thats the case I need to append the year from a second column.